# How to generate a report from a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

I'm trying to generate a report from a MySQL table.
But I cannot figure how to do it.

I have a table like this.

```
+--------+------+------+
| Result | col1 | col2 |
+--------+------+------+
|      1 | A    | B    |
|      1 | C    | D    |
|      1 | E    | F    |
|      2 | G    | H    |
|      2 | I    | J    |
|      2 | K    | L    |
|      2 | M    | N    |
|      3 | O    | P    |
|      4 | Q    | R    |
|      4 | S    | T    |
+--------+------+------+
```

**What is the best way to group the data like this**

```
Result       col1       col2       Total
________________________________________
  1                                  3
________________________________________
              A            B     
----------------------------------------
              C            D
----------------------------------------
              E            F
________________________________________
  2                                  4
________________________________________
             G            H
.
.
.
_________________________________________
Total                                  10
```

I was thinking to use a variable,
and store the first Result, and foreach row
compare it until it changes.
If it changes print the header again with the total
of rows.
and set the value of the variable to the new Result value.

Iterating a table generated by this Query.

```
SELECT
  A.result,
  A.col1,
  A.col2,
  (
    SELECT
        COUNT(Result)
    FROM
        Example AS B
    WHERE
        A.result = b.result
  ) AS Total
FROM
  Example AS A;
```

Using this table

```
+--------+------+------+-------+
| result | col1 | col2 | Total |
+--------+------+------+-------+
| 1      | A    | B    |     3 |
| 1      | C    | D    |     3 |
| 1      | E    | F    |     3 |
| 2      | G    | H    |     4 |
| 2      | I    | J    |     4 |
| 2      | K    | L    |     4 |
| 2      | M    | N    |     4 |
| 3      | O    | P    |     1 |
| 4      | Q    | R    |     2 |
| 4      | S    | T    |     2 |
+--------+------+------+-------+
```

#### Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you print your html you can write that if the actual value is different from the previus one it print another css class that will change the color maybe

Comment: For me it sounds like you have figured out how to do it.

Comment: thank you both!!, I thought that i was wrong. It's the first time i write a report. See you later